# K-fold Cross-Validation - initialise network after each fold or not?

Tags: matlab, validation, neural-network, training-data

I mostly understand how k-fold cross-validation works and have begun implementing it into my MATLAB scripts, however I have two questions.

When using it to select network features (hidden units, weight decay prior and no. iterations in my case). Should I re-intialise the weights after each 'fold', or should I just feed my next training fold into the already trained network (it has weights that have been optimised for the previous fold) ?

It seems that doing the latter should give lower errors as the previous fold of data will be a good approximation of the next, and so the weights will be closer than those initialised randomly from a gaussian distribution.

Additionally, having validated the network using k-fold validation, and chosen network hyper parameters etc., and I want to start using the network, am I right in thinking that I should stop using k-fold validation and just train once, using all of the available data?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should reinitialize the weights after each fold, in order to start with a "blank" network. If you don't do this, then each fold will "leak" into each other, and that's not what K-Fold CV is supposed to do.

After finding the best hyperparameters, yes, you can train it with all the available data. Just remember to keep some hold-out testing data for final testing.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I hoped to hear.